# function parameter receives a int "b" number but print a random number (function calling function)

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

I did commentate where the problem is in the code below, when pow function is called, the exp parameter goes crazy. The goal of the code is to receive a user input and solve that expression x/(1+t)^n.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

float val();
float pow();

float val(float x, int n, float t) {

    float res = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("exp = %d\n", i+1); // real value exp start equals 1
        res += x / pow(1 + t, i+1);
    }
    return res;
}

float pow(float base, int exp) {
    int i = 0;
    float res = 1;
    printf("exp = %d", exp); // here starts the problem 
    if (exp == 1) {
        return base;

    }
    while (i < exp) {
        res *= base;
        i++;
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        printf("exp = %d\n", exp);
        getchar();
    }
    return res;
}

main() {
    int n;
    float x, t, res;

    printf("type x,n,t\n");
    scanf("%f %d %f", &x, &n, &t);
    res = val(x, n, t);
    printf("VAL = %f\n", res);


}
```

Output:

```
type x,n,t
6
2
2
exp = 1
exp = 1074266112i = 1
exp = 1074266112
i = 2
exp = 1074266112
```

Whats happening guys?
thanks for your attention :)

Comment: There is a standard library function `pow`, you should call your function something different to avoid linking clashes

Comment: good advice!! did alter to float power(float base, int exp) hope that one doesnt exist already too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use old-style deprecated non-prototyped forward declarations:

```
float val();    /* This syntax should never be used */
float pow();
```

When you declare a function, declare its full prototype:

```
float val(float x, int n, float t);
float pow(float base, int exp);
```

Also, consider using `double` rather than`float`.

---

As might be guessed from the initial results, your program exhibited Undefined Behaviour; in this case, you call `pow` with an argument type incompatible with its parameter type. The old-style deprecated declaration style

```
float pow();
```

does not specify what the parameter types of `pow` are, or even how many it is expecting. In effect, it tells the compiler "Trust me, I'll provide arguments of the correct type."

But it is then impossible to comply with that promise, because `pow` expects a `float` as its first argument, and the compiler performs the default argument promotions on all arguments supplied to functions declared without a prototype. One of the default promotions turns a `float` into a `double`, so it is impossible to provide a `float` argument. Had you used `double`s instead of `float`s, you would not have experienced this particular problem and you would probably continue to use a syntax which has been discouraged for almost 30 years now.

By the way, this problem did not occur in `val` because the definition of `val` occurs before you use it. The definition does specify parameter types, of course, and that fills in the information omitted in the prototype-less forward declaration.

But the bottom line is the simple advice provided above: Do not use old-style function declarations. Every function should be declared with a full prototype specifying the types of all its parameters. (If you need to declare a function with no parameters, use the special parameter list `(void)` instead of an empty parameter list.)

Comment: i made the alterations the output looks better but still strange. Output:              type x,n,t \n
6\n
2\n
2\n
exp = 1 \n
exp = 1exp = 2 \n
exp = 2i = 1 \n
exp = 2 \n
i = 2 \n
exp = 2 \n

Comment: @raijin: I don't see anything wrong with that output.

Comment: An explanation *why* using mixing a `float val()` declaration with a `float val(float x, int n, float t) {...}` definition is bad would be good.  Short answer for those interested:  with a `float val()` **declaration**, the calling code will apply default argument promotions, while the `float val(float x, int n, float t)` definition expects to receive non-promoted arguments.

Comment: @AndrewHenle:  OK, I did that although the explanation only applies to OP's `pow` function, not to `val`. Honestly, I think the mystery is not why this code doesn't work, but rather why it's still common to find people using a syntax which was deprecated probably before they were born.

Answer (score 0):

pow :

```
float pow(float base, int exp) 
{

    float res = 1;
    if (exp > 0)
    {
         while(exp --)
         {
            res *= base;
         }
    }
    else
    {
        while(exp ++)
        {
            res /= base;
        }
    }

    return res;
}

main() 
{
    int i;
    for (i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf("5 ^^ %d = %f\n", i, pow(5.0f,i));
    }
}
```

and complete

```
#include <stdio.h>

float power(float base, int exp) 
{

    float res = 1;
    if (exp > 0)
    {
    while(exp --)
    {
            res *= base;
    }
    }
    else
    {
    while(exp ++)
    {
        res /= base;
    }
    }

    return res;
}

float eq(float x, float t, int n)
{
    return x / power(1 + t, n); 
}

int main() 
{
    float x,t;
    int i,n;

    for (i = -5; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        printf("5 ^^ %d = %f\n", i, power(5.0f,i));
    }

    scanf("%f %f %d\n", &x, &t, &n);
    printf("x = %f, t = %f, n = %d\n", x, t, n);
    printf("1/(1+t)^^n = %f", eq(x, t, n));
}
```

Comment: You should explain what changes you made and why